# Deploying My First Angular 2 to localhost windows

Tags: angular, npm

On Windows, I've Just created my first angular 2 app as described in the quickstart here ...

https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

A very simple application with a plain background and "My first Angular App"

To run it in "Dev", I ran NPM Start.

So if I want to put this app in my localhost, can I just copy the entire folder structure, leaving out node_modules (which from reading around, I gather isn't needed for the app to run ) ? Or is there an NPM function?

Thanks

Comment: actually, looking at this little walk thru, code, it does use node_modules after all :-o sorry about that. So instead of deploying or publishing 17,000 files, how to deploy/publish only what is necessary?

Comment: `angularjs` is the tag for the *original* Angular framework, `angular` is the tag for Angular 2+.

Answer (score 0):

Download [bracket](http://brackets.io)s editor it has an icon at the top right corner called live preview when you hover over it and when you click  on it it'll start up a server on your localhost and you can run you app.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using node modules in your code I don't see why it's needed. If you're still curious about installing the modules, I would look into how to get it into your localhost.

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-windows